# Missing required parameter

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel-8

Esta es la vista donde me da el error puede ser también por la función diffForHumans, antes se ejecutaba todo bastante bien pero de repente me dio un error y no puede ejecutarlo. Antes tenía la función así `{{ $project->created_at->diffForHumans() }}`

```
@section('title', 'Portafolio | ' . $project->title)
    @extends('layout')
    @section('content')
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-10 mx-auto">
            @if($project->image)
            <img class="card-img-top" height="30%" src="/storage/{{$project->image}}" alt="{{$project->title }}">
            @endif
            <div class="bg-white p-5 shadow rounded">
                <h1>{{$project->title}}</h1>
                <p class="text-secondary">{{$project->description}}</p>
                <p class="text-black-50">{{optional($project->created_at)->diffForHumans()}}</p>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between aling-items-center">
                    <a href="{{route('projects.index')}}">Regresar</a>
                    @auth
                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                            @can('update', $project)
                                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{route('projects.edit', $project)}}">Editar</a>
                            @endcan
                            @can('delete', $project)
                                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('delete-project').submit()">Eliminar</a>
                        </div>
                                <form id="delete-project" class="d-none" method="POST" action="{{ route('projects.destroy', $project)}}">
                                @csrf @method('DELETE')
    
                                </form>
                            @endcan
                    @endauth
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    @endsection
```

[image: Error que me sale]

Comment: dice que tu ruta portfolio espera un parametro pero no esta siendo enviado-- me parece que `route('projects.edit', $project)` $project es el problema

Comment: Y que podría hacer para mejorarlo? Es que no soy capaz de averiguarlo, soy nuevo en esto. Muchas graciaas!

Comment: revisa que estas mandando en $project, si no estas mandando nada la ruta se cae

Comment: El problema es que me funcionaba correctamente pero he tocado algo y no sé como arreglarlo, debería mandar el id(clave primaria) para diferenciar a los diferentes proyectos para editar y borrarlos

Comment: si, alli va el ID